# Ajax returns "Not Found" in ASP.NET mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax

I have the following code for HTML button:

```
<div>
    <input type="file" id="excelUpload" name="excelUpload" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Upload Excel" id="btnUploadExcel" />
</div>
```

I have ajax code below:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#btnUploadExcel', function () {
                var $file = new FormData();
                var files = $("#excelUpload").get(0).files;

                // Add the uploaded image content to the form data collection
                if (files.length > 0) {
                    $file.append("ExcelFile", files[0]);
                }

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/api/excels",
                    data: { var1: $file },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert("Error is " + error);
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (!response.Valid) {
                            alert(response.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("File uploaded successfully");
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;// if it's a link to prevent post
            });
        });
```

And I have a controller called ExcelsController.cs with following code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public bool ReadFromExcel(([FromBody]dynamic value)
        {
           var filePath = value.var1.Value;
           return true; 
        }
```

So, when I click on the upload button, the alert dialog in the error portion of the ajax code gets executed which says "Error Not Found". I am assuming my controller code is not even hit because when I debug and put a breakpoint in my controller, it doesn't get to it. I just want to point out that my controller resides in a folder called "controllers/api"  folder and my html resides "Views/product/index". The "Views" and "Controllers" folders are at the same level. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: To hit that method it would be `url: "/api/excels/ReadFromExcel"`

Comment: that didn't work.

Comment: Well you cannot be still getting a `404` - what error are you getting now

Comment: Okay, so I fgured out the part of the problem. My controller did not have a proper namespace. When I fixed it, I  got another message which says  "Unsupported Media Type".  I am using a web api and I want to get the data from the html. I have changed my controller code and api code. Please take a look.

Comment: You cannot send an object containing `FormData` - it needs to be just `data: $file,`, and you should remove the `[FromBody]dynamic value` parameter from the method

Comment: How can I retrieve it in my controller if I remove [FormBody] parameter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179671/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-bangbang).